# ASP.NET VB.NET Protection Level

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Trying to add rows to table on page load. I know you can use jquery and such but for all intents and purposes I cant' right now.

How would I go about getting past protection level error. If i created the object it obviously doesn't link to the HTML page. If I need to create it how do I link it back up to HTML? Here is what I have so far.

ASP.NET Code:

```
<body>
     <asp:table runat="server" id="PastOrderTable" />
</body>
```

VB.NET Code:

```
    Dim test As New TableRow
    Dim testerCell As New TableCell
    testerCell.Text = "1"
    test.Cells.Add(testerCell)
    PastOrderTable.Rows.Add(test)
```

Error:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message:

> BC30451: 'PastOrderTable' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Assuming this is ASP .Net Web Forms, since you didn't say.  The error message is fairly self-explanatory.  Either `PastOrderTable` is not declared in the designer file, or it is declared but not public.

Comment: Yes, it is in ASP.NET Web Forms. I'm just confused why it wouldn't be reachable when a ASP:Button on the same page is.

Comment: Sometimes the designer file and the markup file can get "out of sync" with each other.  Look in the designer file and show us what the declaration for `PastOrderTable` looks like.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7nk04e I'm a little confused is this what you mean?

Comment: No.  There is a designer file, named like `Whatever.Designer.vb` (where "Whatever" is the name of your page).  It contains designer-generated VB code.  That is the code that is created by the designer that you posted a screenshot of.

Comment: I couldn't find the designer.vb I looked in file directory as well and couldn't find it there either. However the error seems to go away if I place a <asp:TableRow/> within the table itself but will only allow me to populate the table once